# How can I create a second partition in all the unallocated space?

Tags: command-line, partitioning

I have a HDD divided in 2 NTFS partitions. I want to delete the second NTFS partition and make a EXT4 new one. I know how to create a partition with `sudo parted /dev/sda mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%`, but now I don't know where the first NTFS partion ends. Is there any method by which I can tell the partitioning tool that I want the partition to automatically occupy all the unallocated space ?

I can only use the CLI, because I have a headless Raspbery Pi...

Thanks !

Comment: I think that's what the default "new partition" command of your partition tool does, allowing you to confirm and to override if you want to.

Comment: Ideed, `fdisk` do that... in the interactive mode. But if I want to do this with `parted` in one single command... ?